# Flow: Can you declare output as a cast of an input type?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I have some logging functions that return `true`/`false` based on whether or not they logged anything, so I can do:

```
if (log.onError((err: ?Error), 'can not do thing')) {
  return;
}
```

I'm trying to fix the annotations for `log.onError` so that it's effectively:

```
function onError(err: ?Error, msg: string): (err: boolean) {
  // log stuff
  return !!err;
}
```

The `(err: boolean)` at the end isn't valid, but it's what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to just write the return type, like this:

```
function onError(err: ?Error, msg: string) : boolean {
  // log stuff
  return !!err;
}
```

Comment: yes, I know that's how it's normally done.  I'm trying to tie the return type to the input so that it can be statically analyzed and the `if` statement can cause flow to filter the type out of code that follows it.  Something like `onError<T: ?Error>(err: T, msg: string) => T` would accomplish the same thing but I'd be losing type information